# Bind textbox to the object from viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

In my MVVM test project I want to bind my textbox to the object from viewmodel:

```
public class ContactViewModel : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Contact _selectedItem;

    public ContactViewModel()
    {
        ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel();
        _selectedItem = contactModel.ContactList[1];  // this contains first contact from the list; 
    }
}

public Contact SelectedContact
{
    get
       {
          return _selectedItem;
       }
}
```

in my Contact class I am overriding ToString Method in order to show first Contact's first name:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return _firstName.ToString();
}
```

And here is my XAML binding:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="SelectedItemTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedContact}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

And for some reason this textbox is always empty. However, if I change

```
public String SelectedContact
{
    get
       {
          return _selectedItem.LastName;
       }
}
```

it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stanislav, you did a mistake in other place. You try to bind to object, binding doesn't know what to show and apply `ToString()` to your `Contact` object. If you overrode `ToString()`, it had to show a returned value of this method. **I created the test app, and it works in this way**!

What I can see in your code, in `ToString()` you return `FirstName`, but in changed `SelectedContact` it is `SecondName` - did you fill first name before?

You wrote in comment that tried to access to first element, but in code you take second element of `ContactList`

Moreover, use binding in this way is incorrect. If you want to access to LastName use next way:

```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedContact.LastName, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

And remove `ToString()` overriding.

**EDIT**: Unlike to other controls where binding is `OneWay` by default in `TextBox` it is `TwoWay` by default. It was done because native behavior of `TextBox` is show and edit value (not only show as in other controls). Moreover if you don't plan to change value (you don't plan, because `ContactModel` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) it is recommended to use `OneTime` mode (for performance).

`TwoWay` has some restriction - you can't use it for read-only property (`SelectedContact` is read-only in your code). Because binding can't change the value in this case - make sense. It is strange that app lunched in your case and `TextBox` was empty, because in my case I get the error "*A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'SelectedContact' of type 'WpfApplication1.ContactViewModel'.*" until I changed binding mode in `TextBox`.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the Binding mode to OneWay and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you followed this Article on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Alltough the article says, that the standard representation of a ListBox is a List of ToString representation of its contents, this is not the case for every other element.

I would highly recommend to create a DataBinding Template for you Contact class, it's a much cleaner way to implement this behaviour than overriding ToString.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it, I just had to change my TextBox to the TextBlock and now everything works properly !

It seems like TextBlock does understand how to show objects, but TextBox doesn't.

Comment: `TextBox` needs a `set` accessor if you want to bind the `Text` property, since by default, the `Text` property binds as `TwoWay`

Comment: Nope... even with set accessor, textbox doesn't want to show the object.

Comment: Hrrm that's strange, I thought you need a `set` accessor to do two-way bindings. Must be wrong then :)